# How to change <td id="totalCell"> to <td><input id="totalCell">

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me how to change td id="totalCell" to input id="totalCell" because i want to add onblurr in the input but it is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTotal(s){
var newTotal=0;
var allEls=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i=0;i<allEls.length;i++)
{
if(allEls[i].getAttribute("name")!=s)continue;
if(isNaN(allEls[i].value))continue;
newTotal+=new Number(allEls[i].value);
}
var e=document.getElementById("totalCell");
e.firstChild.data="  Total =  "+newTotal;
} 
</script>
<html>
<body>
<table><tr>
<td><input type="text" onblur="updateTotal('putts[]')" size="2" name="putts[]"         maxlength="1" value=""/></td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="updateTotal('putts[]')" size="2" name="putts[]" maxlength="1" value=""/></td>
<td><input type="text" onblur="updateTotal('putts[]')" size="2" name="putts[]" maxlength="1" value=""/></td>
<td id="totalCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ? ... do you want to handle onblur for input field ?

Comment: yes i want to add onblur but it is for another javascript

Comment: U want to add id atrribute to input tag?

Comment: yes but since the javascript is using getElementsByTagName("*"), the input tag is not working

Comment: do you want to add input box inside td id="totalCell" with total of all input boxes?

Comment: yes Bhushan. Any idea how?

Comment: example
<td><input type = "text id" = "totalCell" onblur: "javascript:calcGTotal()" ></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to replace `<td id=“totalCell”>` by `<td><input id=“totalCell”>` do like

```
//selecting the existing dom element to be replaced
var OldElement =document.getElementById("totalCell");

//building the new element to replace old 
var NewTd = document.createElement("td");
var myInput = document.createElement("input");
myInput.setAttribute("id", "totalCell");
NewTd.appendChild(myInput);

//replace old by new
OldElement.parentNode.replaceChild(NewTd, OldElement);
```

see this [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/63C2u/1/)

Comment: <td><input type="text" onblur="updateTotal()" size="2"  size="10" maxlength="10" value=""/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="totalCell"></td>
i tried like this but it is not working